# Transform input in dropdown and insert php in js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I will know how to transform a input in dropdown. My problem, I need to take information language in php and inject in js to create a dropdown.

Thank you

the line :

```
  cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bot_language[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
```

all the script

```
<?php
// display all language (1 = english - 2 = french)
  $values_languages_id = Language::getAllLanguage(false);

      $output = <<<EOD
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#addRowBot").on("click", function () {
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bot_response[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
```

//this line must be converted in dopdown

```
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bot_language[]' + counter + '"/></td>';



      cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDelBot btn btn-md btn-danger" id="deleteRowBot" value="{$button_delete}"></td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      $("table.order-list-bot").append(newRow);
      counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list-bot").on("click", ".ibtnDelBot", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
    counter -= 1
  });
});
</script>
EOD;
  return $output;
```

Comment: my advice is, stop doing this kind of process. what's best is, you create an endpoint, where you will send values to it and return an object or whatever data you like. use an $.ajax call fetch your data and control it from your js side

Comment: ok, how to make that, I am 0 in js. for this line :       cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bot_language[]' + counter + '"/></td>';

Comment: try changing the `newRow.append(cols)` to `newRow.append($(cols))`